# azure container_client delete_blobs causes oom

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure blob SDK python version. Here is how I do blobs deletion:

```
blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="myprefix") 
container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs)
```

if `blobs` here return a large amount of blob objects, the above code crashes.
What is the standard practice here? Are there other ways to do batch deletion?

### Update:

reply to @Ivan Yang:
This is slightly different from your solution. I ran it but got error

> There is a partial failure in the batch operation.

```
blobs = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="myprefix")
blobs_list = list(blobs)
i in range(0, len(blobs_list), 10):
    container_client.delete_blobs(*blobs_list[i: i+10])
```

Comment: do you remember how many blobs returned which cause the issue?

Comment: and please also provides a completed sample, it will be easier to reproduce and fix.

Comment: It is 190 blobs and I found each blob is an object instead of a string. That explains why it explodes memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better specify how many blobs you are trying to delete by using `delete_blobs` method. Then it's easier for debug.

As a workaround, you can fetch a certain number(like 10 blobs) of blobs each time, then delete until the `continuation token` is null.

Here is the sample code:

```
#define a continuation token
continuation_token = None

while True:
    #fetch 10 blobs each time
    blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="xxx",results_per_page=10).by_page(continuation_token=continuation_token)
    list_segment=[blob.name for blob in list(next(blob_list))]
    container_client.delete_blobs(*list_segment)
    
    continuation_token = blob_list.continuation_token

    if not continuation_token:
        break
```

Comment: Great solution. Another doubt is why cannot we just get all blobs first and then do a batch deletion of size 10?

Comment: Never mind. You solution works perfectly fine! Thanks